# Is there a library for auto-saving user input (continously)?

Tags: html, angularjs, web-applications

I am using node.js - Angularjs.

I want to auto-save content both online (while user remains online) and offline (incase the user unexpectedly disconnects).

I can perform the same using ng-change (to monitor) and writing the database-saving code.

And similarly, to write locally (for offline) using html-5 `localStorage`.

Instead of the above, is there an awesome library, for the same purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one seems to be popular. Save form data to browser local storage.
https://github.com/simsalabim/sisyphus

Comment: Is there similarly a library for auto-saving to a database or something?